# How to deploy to specific URL

Tags: java, grizzly

I have 2 grizzly applications I'd like to run side by side on different URLs on the same server.  When I change my url from `localhost` to `api.url.local` for local debugging it throws a `java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException`.  Is there something I need to do in order for java to recognize another URL (ie - modify hosts file)?  Or am I going in the wrong direction?

I'm currently on Windows but will be deploying to Linux. (If it were up to me, I'd run Linux)

```
public class Main {

    public static final URI BASE_URI = getBaseURI();

    private static URI getBaseURI() {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(9998).build();
    }

    protected static HttpServer startServer() throws IOException {
        ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("com.my.package.api.resources");
        rc.getFeatures()
            .put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, true);

        return GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, rc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext annotationCtx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);

        HttpServer httpServer = startServer();

        System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at " + "%sapplication.wadl\nHit enter to stop it...", BASE_URI, BASE_URI));
        System.in.read();
        httpServer.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider to use different ports (TCP ports) for these apps? As I understand these 2 apps will run on separate JVM instances, right?

Comment: They'd be the same instance.  I did consider ports, but I'm wondering if that's necessary.  Is it possible to just deploy to 2 different URLs, so JVM will map the URL to the application that's running?

Comment: If you want to use one port you have to share HttpServer instance for both applications. How do these apps look like?

Comment: @alexey -I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. They would both be web applications.

Comment: can you pls. share app#1 and app#2 code (the most important part is initialization code, that inits and starts Grizzly)?

Comment: Just to clarify: in your question you state that you'd like two different URLs, jet the details seem to indicate that you're mainly interested in having separate hostnames. Is that right? http://api.url.local/one and http://api.url.local/two *are* two different URLs, though they share a hostname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running two different applications under different urls on the same machine with one ip address is quite easy.  But can require some setup depending on what you want to do.

My assumption is that you're doing this on your development machine.  The biggest issue here is that the two servers require different port numbers.

Server #1
`http://localhost:8080/`

Server #2
`http://localhost:8081/`

If you want named instances instead.  You will have to update your hosts file to point the named instance you want to your local machine.  BUT, you'll still have to do separate ports per application.

Server #1
`http://api.url.local:8080/`

Server #2
`http://api.url.local2:8081/`

You will also have to update your tomcat (I'm assuming you're using tocmat) config.  In the  element, I believe you will have to update the 'name' attribute to be the name of your application's URL.

Friendly warning, if you are using the same IP Address, but different host names, SSL certificates will not work very well.  Typically in that sort of setup you will need either a wildcard or unified communications certificate.

When you deploy to production, I would recommend using Apache HTTP Server as a proxy to your two applications and have two separate IP Address' unless you can use a SSL wildcard or a unified communications certificate.

---

This part of the answer is for if you wanted to run one application under two different URLs.

Proxy your application with a [Apache Http Server](http://httpd.apache.org/) instance and use [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) to forward your two different server names or ip address' to the same Java instance.

My recommendation though, just run two instances of your application.  Don't worry too much about resources, hardware is really cheep and worth a lot less then worrying about how to run one instance for two different sites.

Comment: I'm actually trying to run 2 separate applications on 2 different URLs.  Not run 2 URLs for the same application instance - though I can actually see that being useful as well.

Comment: So the only way to do this is via 2 port numbers?

Comment: Or you can do it with two ip address'.  I'm not sure how easy that is on a windows machine.  For a linux machine, it is fairly easy.  Each app would be listening to the same port (80, 8080, 433, 8443) but on different ip address'.

Comment: You can also proxy via apache/mod_proxy by going to two different urls, but behind the scenes you're still going to have to run your tomcat instances on different ports.  The only way to run on the same port is to have two ip address' on one machine.